# Nginx + 1 Rails app + Multiple Domains + 1 session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, nginx

Here's my situation, I have a Rails 4 app that can be accessed by multiple domains, depending on the domain, the content changes.

Say the main domain is `domain1` and all the other domains just use Nginx's `proxy_pass` to forward the requests to `domain1`, this is all working fine except that when a user logs in `domain2`, rails sets the session for `domain1` so the user in `domain2` remains logged out because the session is not set for `domain2`.

I understand cookies can't be shared across different domains, but since it's the same app handling all those domains, surely something should be possible.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here's where I'm at:

- I added a custom header to the proxy pass that contains the domain from where the app is being accessed.
- I wrote a middleware that checks this header and sets the `rack.session.options domain` to the domain specified in the custom header.
- I've enabled the middleware in the `development.rb` and `production.rb` files.
- I've added `:domain => :all` to the `session_store` options.
- In the controllers I have checked and the `session.options[:domain]` is correctly set to `domain2`.

Yet I am unable to set a session from `domain2`, what am i missing here?

**CODE**

**Middleware**

```
class ProxyPassCookie

    def initialize app
        @app = app
    end

    def call env
        host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first

        #rack attaches HTTP_ to all headers
        dom = env["HTTP_WLDOMAIN"].blank? ? host : env["HTTP_WLDOMAIN"]
        env["rack.session.options"][:domain] = ".#{dom}"
        @app.call(env)
    end

end
```

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', :domain => :all
```

**config/environments/development.rb | production.rb**

```
config.middleware.use "ProxyPassCookie"
```

There's got to be a way to do this, any input appreciated!

Comment: Is it the same problem as accessing to a rails app through `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000` ? I don't have any solution but the problems is interesting

Comment: yes in essence i believe it is the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this, all my Rails stuff was fine, the problem was in the Nginx configs, more specifically that the main domain was using SSL while the others weren't so i guess Nginx was not setting the cookies for security reasons.